# How to make a liquid without doing a simulation

Tags: mesh

Is there a way to make honey in blender without running a simulation? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. If you wish to do that honey only for static shot (like simple render of the scene) then you could sculpt it manually (it might be complex depending on how much that honey should be realistic). If you're going for animation then I think  no way without creating a simulation baked further on.

Comment: Sure it's possible. There are different possibilities, depending on do you need it to be an animation or still.If it's for still, then preparing a mesh in appropriate shape and giving it yellow glass material would be a good start. If it's for animation, you can use shapekeys, curve modifier, curve with shapekeys, possibilities are endless.